# How to add a password to an SD card?

Tags: sd

I want to build an embedded system that reads external data and logs it to a file saved in an SD card. However this system is accessed through a password and I want either the SD card or the file in it to use this password as well. How can I do it?
About the file, I thought of saving it with a .CSV extension because it uses rows and columns. Can this type of files have password? Any suggestions?

To be more specific with the question:
I will use a microcontroller, programmed with C language. What commands should I send to the SD card in order to be password-protected? Or, what is the format of a file in order to have an access password?

EDIT:
I want to add a password so that only the user is able to open the file and read it using his/her PC.

Comment: Notably, the answer to this question [really](http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-use-lockunlock-mmc) is [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29).

Answer (score 3):

The SD card has password protection built into the standards.  [Here](https://www.sdcard.org/home/) you can read the standards for SD cards to learn how it works.  Below is a link to a project for locking/unlocking a SD card with an Atmel microcontroller.

[SDLocker2](http://www.seanet.com/~karllunt/sdlocker2.html)

Comment: But note that most devices which interface with SD cards, including computer-based SD readers, **do not** support password protection. You will likely be unable to use the card while protection is enabled.

Comment: @duskwuff I want to add a password so that only the user is able to open the file and read it (using his/her PC). So, according to your comment, this will not be possible if I use the solution provided above, is that what you mean?

Comment: Correct. SD card passwords protect the entire card from being used, not individual files.

Comment: @duskwuff Strictly speaking, this is only true when the SD reader is connected via USB Mass storage endpoint (or a similar interface) which doesn't support raw SD commands. Many internal card readers accept arbitrary SD commands. You still need software to send these commands though.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Right, I mean from a practical perspective. Even if the hardware can technically send the commands to unlock the card, the drivers probably won't handle that case. Inserting a password-protected card will likely result in an error message or nothing at all -- not a password prompt.